# How can I add force to an object at a certain degree that rotates?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I have an object and arrow the arrow rotates (follows the mouse). I need to take the rotation from the arrow and apply this force to an object, but the object rotates and the arrow takes it rotation.

My code

```
angl = transform.localEulerAngles.z-bean.transform.localEulerAngles.z;
rb.AddForce(new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angl) * 500f, Mathf.Sin(angl) * 500f));
```

The script is attached to the arrow. And the arrow is a child of the object.

Comment: so dont make the arrow a child of the object?